# Edit a configuration file with sections using bash

Tags: bash

Iam writing a bash script to change a configuration file. The config file contains section headers and may include the same key / value pairs for each section.

Sample config file:

```
Header one
  key value
  key2 foobar
Header two
  key bar
```

I want to replace a keys value for a specific section header without touching the same key on a different section. E.g. replace the value "value" of "Header one/key" with some arbitrary value without changing the value bar of "Header two/key"

The actual section headers follow the pattern provided in the sample (some fixed word + a non fixed part).

A came up with a solution for value replacement using sed:

```
# Set a configuration value                                                                                                                                                                                        
# Args:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#   1) The config key                                                                                                                                                                                              
#   2) The new value                                                                                                                                                                                               
#   3) The config file                                                                                                                                                                                             
function set_config_value() {                                                                                                                                                                                      
  sed -i "s/^\s*($1\s*\).*\$/\1$2/" $3                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

But Iam clueless how to restrict the replacement to a certain section of the configuration file.

I Would like to come up with a solution that is somewhat similar to

```
# Set a configuration value                                                                                                                                                                                        
# Args:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#   1) The config key                                                                                                                                                                                              
#   2) The new value
#   3) The config section header                                                                                                                                                                                            
#   4) The config file                                                                                                                                                                                             
function set_config_value() {                                                                                                                                                                                      
  ???                                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

**Edit:** 
For questions about the actual configuration file: Assume the the whole text of the section header is known when settings the value. No matter if it is called "header one", "foo" or "foobar bar bar".

**Edit 2:** 
Sed might not be the best tool for this kind of task. Using awk, assuming the key values pair lines start with white space:

```
function set_confg_value() {
  awk -i inplace -v section="$1" -v key="$2" -v value="$3" '
    BEGIN {
      in_section = 0
    }

    # Set the in_section flag when entering the requested section 
    $0~section {
      in_section = 1
    }

    # Process matched section 
    $0~"^\\s+"key {
      if (in_section) {
        print "  "$1" "value
        skip = 1
      }
    }

    # Reset in_section flag 
    $0~"(?!"section")^\\S" {
      in_section = 0
    }

    # Print the rest 
    /.*/ {
      if (skip)
        skip = 0
      else 
        print $0
    }
    ' "$4"
}
```

Comment: Unless you describe the config file's structure any answer to this question will be based on assumptions, and likely to fail to work with actual input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current attempt has some problems.

```
# Your code
sed -i "s/^\s*($1\s*\).*\$/\1$2/" $3
```

After `$1` you want at least one whitespace (you don't want to match key2), use '+'.
You would like the keep first whitespace(s) after the replacement, put it in the match.
Maybe you get additional spaces after a short key, so put the spaces after the key in the match too.
You don't want to match `$`. With the backslash it is a character. You don't need to match end-of-line, the `.*` will match everything until end-of-line.
How about a config file with a space in its name? Quote `$3`.
And the `\s` doesn't work in plain `sed`. Try `-r`.
I deleted the `-i`, so you can test without changing the file:

```
sed -r "s/^(\s*$1\s+).*$/\1$2/" "$3"
```

When you want to limit this code to a section, use `/start/,/end/`. How do you know something is a header? In your example the header lines are called header, but that will not be the case in your real config file. When the headers look like `[section]`, change the solution beneath. The solution beneat assumes that all lines that don't start with whitespace is a header.

```
# Set a configuration value                                                                                                                                                                                        
# Args:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#   1) The config key                                                                                                                                                                                              
#   2) The new value
#   3) The config section header                                                                                                                                                                                            
#   4) The config file                                                                                                                                                                                             
function set_config_value() {
   key="$1"
   val="$2"
   header="$3"
   file="$4"
   # first test this without the -i flag
   sed -ir "/^${header}$/,/^[^\s]/ s/^(\s*${key}\s+).*$/\1${val}/" "${file}"
}
```

This solution should work for your sample config, but will fail when `${key}` or `${value}` has a special character (try `key=/`).
You should use a solution that doesn't try to understand the strings given. My first thought would be `awk`, but make your own choice. Look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137643/57293 .

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use line-based search end replace, like `sed` does. You need to remember the context, i.e., where in the file you are. You have to read the file line by line and keep track of which section you're in. If you're in the right section, find the key, and replace the value.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

# Set a configuration value                                                                                                 
# Args:                                                                                                                     
#   1) The config key                                                                                                       
#   2) The new value
#   3) The config section header                                                                                            
#   4) The config file                                                                                                      
function set_config_value() {
    key="$1"
    new="$2"
    header="$3"
    file="$4"

    tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    headerRegex='^Header (\S+)$'
    keyRegex="\s*$key\s*"

    insection=""
    IFS=''
    while read -r line
    do
        # Check for the next header
        if [[ "$line" =~ $headerRegex ]]
        then
            # Is it the one we're looking for?
            if [ "$header" == "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" ]
            then
                insection="1"
            else
                insection=""
            fi
        fi
        # If we are in the right section:
        if [ -n "$insection" ]
        then
            # and we look at the right key
            if [[ "$line" =~ $keyRegex ]]
            then
                # change it
                line="  $key $new"
            fi  
        fi
        # Print the line, either as it was or modified
        echo "$line" >> "$tmpfile"
    done < "$file"

    mv "$tmpfile" "$file"
}

set_config_value "key" "new value" "two" "in.cfg"
```

Does it have to be bash, btw? This Perl script is much shorter, and uses Perl's inline editing (`-i` flag) instead of manually messing with temporary files:

```
perl -pi -e 'if (m/Header (\w+)/) { 
        $insection = ($1 eq $section);
    } 
    if ($insection && m/^(\s*$key\s*)/) {
        $_ = "$1$value\n";
    }
' -s -- -key=key -value="new value" -section=two in.cfg
```